# Acessing likes on comments an videos in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone suggest how to track the comments and other objects (videos,photos,etc) which a user likes in facebook? Assuming that the user has registerd to my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FQL with the like table.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/
Reference includes examples.

But you can't get a list pf everything the user likes. If you know what object you want to track you can also use the link_stat table:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/